# Linux keyboard/terminal/kernel input buffer

Tags: linux, keyboard, buffer, linux-device-driver, glibc

I want to know where exactly (terminal, keyboard driver, libc, linux kernel, ....?) is stored the text which the user enters in a console application before pressing enter key.

So the use case is like that:

1. The user opens a terminal or runs any other console program.
2. The above program invokes some library call to read input from STDIN like gets, scanf functions (ultimately invokes read system call).
3. The user enters some text and ultimately presses enter.
4. The above program gets the text into the buffer.

Screenshot of this scenario until pressing enter key is given in the following screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h1Du.png)

I'd like to know:

1. Where the text is stored before the user presses enter (keyboard driver, kernel, terminal, etc.?).
2. How long is that buffer (I assume it is a buffer).

Comment: Unread data is stored in the TTY line discipline's buffer - that is the `char read_buf[N_TTY_BUF_SIZE]` member of `struct n_tty_data` in "drivers/tty/n_tty.c". The buffer can hold `N_TTY_BUF_SIZE` characters (there is no unused "sentinel" position). `N_TTY_BUF_SIZE` is defined as 4096 in "include/linux/tty.h".

Comment: However, shells that read input from the terminal interactively to do sophisticated line editing, such as Bash with the readline library, and things like interactive text editors (Vim, nano, etc.) do not read the terminal in canonical, line by line input mode. They read the terminal in noncanonical input mode so that characters are read as they being typed. The unread data is still in the line discipline buffer though.